# WordPress postmeta table size, why base 64 encoded images removal from db didn't decrease the size?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, post-meta

I have a WordPress website, unfortunately the postmeta table size is increased to 25 GB, I was storing base 64 encoded images in the postmeta table as well

In order to reduce postmeta table size, I have run a script and stored images in directory and replace the base 64 meta value with one liner image URL. I was expecting the postmeta table size to be reduced which is almost the same. base 64 encoded string is a long string of KBs whereas the one line URL is just of bytes but still no significant difference in postmeta table size.

Answer (score 0):

You should reorganize the table storage to reclaim the storage space and optimize the data structure: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimize-table.html